# How to send requests to SQLite in Rust in parallel

Tags: sql, sqlite, rust, async-await

I want to send some queries to SQL in Rust. To achieve this I'm using the crate `sqlx`. I send queries to my database file from separate coroutines. And the code works okay if the amount of coroutines is about 1000. If there's more, there's an error

```
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Database(SqliteError { code: 5, message: "database is locked" })', src\main.rs:56:43
```

I understand that 10 thousand coroutines is too much for one file, but I expect a corouting to wait until the database is unlocked rather than return an error.

Here's my code

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use tokio::task::JoinHandle;
use sqlx::sqlite::SqlitePool;

async fn routine(pool: &SqlitePool, age: i32, id: i32) -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    if age % 2 == 0 {
        sqlx::query!("UPDATE users SET salary = salary + 1 WHERE id = ?1", id).execute(pool).await?;
        let row = sqlx::query!(r#"SELECT salary FROM users WHERE id = ?1"#, id)
            .fetch_one(pool)
            .await?;
        Ok(format!("{}: {}", id, row.salary))
    } else {
        let res = sqlx::query!(r#"SELECT salary FROM users WHERE age = ?1 ORDER BY id"#, age)
            .fetch_all(pool)
            .await?
            .iter()
            .map(|it| it.salary.to_string())
            .collect::<Vec<String>>()
            .join(", ");
        Ok(res)
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let n = std::env::args().nth(1).unwrap().parse().unwrap(); // drops if n is 10_000
    let pool = SqlitePool::connect("sqlite://database.db").await.unwrap();

    let handles: Vec<JoinHandle<_>> = (1..n).map(|_| {
        let pool = pool.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            routine(&pool, 0, 0).await.unwrap()
        })
    }).collect();

    for handle in handles {
        handle.await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

Could you please explain how to wait and not to get errors?

Comment: "Database is locked" usually is raised when the lock timeout expires, which means the lock could not be acquired for 30 seconds. This likely means you need to lower the amount of concurrent tasks, not increase it. SQLite is not designed for high-contention scenarios; consider using a proper RDBMS. Alternatively, use your own queue for running queries instead of relying on expensive OS-level locking mechanisms, as SQLite does.

Comment: Thank you for the aswer. So, there's no solution to make an extra amount of workers to wait until other workers done the task?

Comment: https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/451 may be relevant

Comment: There is, but just firing off all of the tasks at once and relying on SQLite locking is not a good way of doing so.

Comment: Consider: SQLite works by writing to a SINGLE file. This means, at any time, at most ONE writing query can be active.

Comment: Instead of starting a new thread for each task, consider implementing a Threadpool or similar with a limited total number of threads, and use it to queue all your tasks. https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-02-multithreaded.html

Comment: @mhutter, these are not threads. Thast tokio's coroutines and the do run in a thread pool

Comment: Aah, I see. So you’ll have 10’000 coroutines that all yield because they wait on the file lock.